# Creating a roslaunch file that includes nodes from several packages

Tags: ros

In my Ros Workspace (ws), there are 3 packages in src folder. And in each package, there is a node (contained in scripts folder) which is written using python. I need to write a roslaunch file that runs all 3 nodes at once.

Folder structure

```
ws
  -src
    -pkg1
       -scripts/node1.py
    -pkg2
       -scripts/node2.py
    -pkg3
       -scripts/node3.py
  -launch *#I want to keep the launch file in here.*
```

Can someone help me or point me out on how to write the launch file combining multiple packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roslaunch makes this fairly easy as it includes a tag for what package to launch a node from. Take the following example:

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="pkg1" type="node1.py" name="node1">
        <param name="some_param1" value="value1">
    </node>
    <node pkg="pkg2" type="node2.py" name="node2">
        <param name="some_param2" value="value2">
    </node>
</launch>
```

Comment: I made the launch folder in src/, but when using command roslaunch I cannot specify a package since I created it outside of all packages.

Comment: I added the launch file into an existing package (pkg1) and now it works, but I the other two packages are not idenfied when launching the launch file. How can I point that nodes from being inside of a different package?

Comment: @d0ppL3G how are you trying to run the launch file? If all the files are built and installed it shouldn’t matter what package they are in, as long as your launching from the install directory.

Comment: I don't have an install directory, just 'build' and 'devel'

Comment: @d0ppL3G that’s your install directory. You need to make sure your CMakeLists.txt is actually building all of the correct files. If they all get built in that directory it’ll work.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could work for you. (assuming you are not using ROS2)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
    <node pkg="pkg1" type="node1.py" name="node1">
    </node>
    <node pkg="pkg2" type="node2.py" name="node2">
    </node>
    <node pkg="pkg3" type="node3.py" name="node3">
    </node>
</launch>
```

If I remember correctly, the launch file can start any node, independent of packages. I usually create an additional package (and name it for example `startup`) and use it simply for my launch files.
[This reference](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML) should have everything documented that you need. You'll find the details to launch a node [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node).